# log4j container logging on Kubernetes

Tags: logging, log4j, kubernetes

Does anyone know how to redirect log4j logs to central Kubernetes logging

Testing on GKE right now but as I understand Kubernetes uses Fluentd by default, doesn't it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is configure log4j to send its logs to stdout and/or stderr. That'll cause them to be shipped to whichever central logging service your cluster was configured with (Google Cloud Logging if you're on GKE).

Comment: this is what i do but my services who use log4j don't seem to output logs in the GCE logging system: i see the Kubernetes logs, not the container internal logs. what am I missing here?

Comment: If you're getting the Kubernetes logs, it's probably more likely that your services' logs are getting drowned out by the Kubernetes logs (we plan to remove them because they can get too noisy). Click on the fourth dropdown in the log viewer, the one that says "All logs". Hopefully your containers will be listed there, and clicking on one will show you the logs from it.

Comment: If they don't show up there, can you try running `kubectl logs <pod-name>` on one of your pods to make sure that the logs are properly getting written to stdout/stderr for the docker daemon to persist them?

Comment: I know I can get logs with kubectl logs but I want to use the gke logging facility to set alerts etc... I will double check to see if they don't show but zk and kafka are also noisy services so I'm surprised

Comment: Sorry about that! It'll be changed in Kubernetes 1.1, and perhaps patched into a 1.0.x release sooner if enough people get bit by it.

Answer (score 0):

We're building a product that allows pulling logs from Kubernetes pods based on a simple configuration: https://github.com/parseablehq/collector

This would allow pulling logs from a container logging in Log4J format.